# How to check if a file is existing or not using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a written a script to check if a file is existing or not and send me a mail on this. But its not working properly. Really appreciate if any suggestions or solutions provided..
My script is as below..

```
SET file1=E:\Program.* 

Set vLogFile=C:\logfile1.log 
if exist %file1% goto fileexists 
goto nofile 

:fileexists 
echo "File exist" > %vLogFile% 
--my required mail sending info here-- 
goto end 
:nofile 
echo "No file exist" > %vLogFile% 
--my required mail sending info here-- 
goto end
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? What are the contents of the root of E:\ ?

Comment: Other than the fact that Windows 7 won't let me write to c:\, this works for me with file1=c:\dev (an existing directory with files in it on my system).

Comment: Are there any spaces in the filenames? If so, add quotation marks around the path `"%file%"` so that spaces will be included in the path.

Comment: Hi all.. when I run the script it is sending me a mail saying file exists even if it there or not as I have given file exists statement first.. else if I give no file exist statement first, if I run the script it sends a mail that no file exists..

Comment: The actual file which I wanted to check is a file of type "File"(thats what I can see in its properties) whose name is "Program". So, I want to check this Program file exists or not in the E drive..

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an `:end` label?

If you use `goto :EOF` instead of `goto end` then you don't need a label.

Answer (score 2):

You need a better syntax with all double quotes:

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET "file1=E:\Program.*"

Set "vLogFile=C:\logfile1.log" 
if exist "%file1%" goto :fileexists 
goto :nofile 

:fileexists 
>"%vLogFile%" echo "File exist"
--my required mail sending info here-- 
goto end 
:nofile 
>"%vLogFile%" echo "No file exist"
--my required mail sending info here-- 
goto end
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the response. but when I run this it is sending the no file exist message irrespective of the file existance in the E drive..

Answer (score 1):

I got my issue resolved. Below is the script after I made changes and it is working fine now as per my requirements.

```
SET file1=Program 
Set vLogFile=C:\logfile1.log 
cd \ 
e: 
dir %file1% /s /b > %vLogFile% 
if errorlevel 1 ( goto mail1) else (goto mail2) 

:mail1 
--my code of lines for sending mail-- 
goto END 

:mail2 
--my code of lines for sending mail-- 
goto END 

:END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning the type `File` in one of your comments. If I understand it correctly, you are talking about the file type as shown by Windows Explorer or the Properties dialog box. When writing batch files, however, it is easier to deal with file *extensions*. Now, the file type called simply `File` suggests to me that this file that you are trying to verify the existence of has *no extension*, i.e. its name is just `Program`, as opposed to `Program.something`.

However, the mask that you are using in the `IF EXIST` command, `Program.*`, would match both the `Program` with no extension and a `Program` with an arbitrary extension, i.e. `Program.txt`, `Program.exe`, `Program.I.cannot.imagine.what.else` etc. Perhaps, there's a `Program` file of a type other than `File` in the `E:\` directory, and that causes the script to always call the `:fileexists` branch.

If you want to check for the existence of specifically `Program`, just specify the name as is, do not use the mask `Program.*`. In other words, change this line

```
SET file1=E:\Program.*
```

to this

```
SET file1=E:\Program
```

Comment: Hi, I got my issue resolved. Below is the script after I made changes and it is working fine now as per my requirements.. Hope this will help you..

SET file1=Program

Set vLogFile=C:\logfile1.log

cd \
e:


dir %file1% /s /b > %vLogFile%

if errorlevel 1 ( goto mail1) else (goto mail2)
:mail1

--my code of lines for sending mail--

goto END

:mail2
--my code of lines for sending mail--

goto END

:END

Comment: @sudheer: Thank you. It may be better if you post that as an answer, though. You'll be able to [format the code nicely](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#link-code "Markdown Help: Code and Preformatted Text") then. (It's perfectly fine here to answer one's own question. After some time you'll even be able to [accept your answer formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") as the one that solved the problem.)